# SRS + SPF for Exchange Server

Tags: exchange, spf

Is there a specific way to enable SRS on Exchange, or a similar function, on a SPF enabled domain?

I have a SPF Record set to ~all, and noticed that out of office (OOO) emails are failing due to them containing a blank MAIL FROM in the header. The recipient doesn't receive the automatic response, but the person that is OOO does get the initial email and their reply's do go through since they have a MAIL FROM value in the headers.